# SQL make 2 columns into 1 from 1 table keep all rows in SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, fuse

I am dealing with a DB whose transaction table could have been split up into 2, but dev team decided it was not worth it.

Now I want to retrieve the transactions and their dates. Problem is : table includes 2 different types of transactions, meaning: I have 2 date columns : "transaction_date" and "beta_transaction_date" (I am modifying the names for confidentiality).

For *my* data analysis, date column is one single datum. How do I select a fused date column, transactions, and beta_transaction? (I should get corresponding Null values for either quantity in one of the transaction column for every quantity populated in either beta_transaction or standard transaction)

I considered something around those lines

```
SELECT date AS d, b_date AS d, transaction, b_transaction FROM transaction
```

... Could this be the way to go? I can't test right now but I don't think this works.

If my question is nonsense pls excuse me and just delete it, I am a super beginner. I am using Postgres 12 but don't think this is specific to Postgres.

Comment: Are both date columns always populated, or is one always null while the other is always populated?

Comment: Do you want to list each transaction twice, like "[date], value" followed by "[other date], -value"?

Comment: no it's one or the other, when beta_transaction related data is populated, corresponding null data is populated for normal transactions columns. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can use `COALESCE(transaction_date, beta_transaction_date)`. If the fitst value is null, it returns the second value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think this might be what you need:

```
SELECT [date] as d
    ,  transaction 
FROM   table1
WHERE  [date] is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT b_date as d
    ,  b_transaction
FROM   table1
WHERE  b_date is not null
```

This has the advantage that if you have a row that has non-null values for *both* dates, you'll pick up both sets of dates and transaction values.

Another way would be to have just a single `SELECT` statement, with a `COALESCE([date], b_date)` or `ISNULL([date], b_date)` expression, but, if you had non-null values in both date columns, you'd wind up returning the info from the first one listed in the function and ignoring the second. The option with the `UNION ALL` will return all the data where `[date]` is non null, *and* all the data where `b_date` is non-null.

This may also be able to take advantage of any indexes built over the date fields (for any further sorting or selecting), whereas the results of `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` would not.

Comment: Hey Ann, was going through the COALESCE and it seems to connect all my dots, can't test right now but will, and come back here, thanks an have a good day on ur end! :)

Comment: @Zuko36  Great! Good luck!

Comment: Hello Ann, actually the UNION ALL method didn't work as wanted as it fused the transaction and b_transaction columns together too into a 'transaction' column. I needed those kept separated even at the cost of getting null values for each row in either one column. Also by design wouldn't get scenario of non null values in both date and b_date for one same date. Thanks still of course and thx @the-impaler too

Comment: I see!  Well, it sounds like @The-Impaler's solution is the right one for you!